# Wrong FAB position on layout

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

I am using Programmatically defined RelativeLayout and I have added a FAB inside RelativeLayout but the position of FAB is wrong & the Icon also is not shown...

Here's the code I'm using -

```
final RelativeLayout frameLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    fab = new FloatingActionButton(this);
            fab.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.more));

            fablp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            fablp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
            fablp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT);
            int mrgn = 16;
            int xp = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, mrgn, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            fablp.setMargins(0,0,xp,xp);
            frameLayout.addView(fab);
```

Comment: not sure but, you are using `RelativeLayout` params but adding view to frameLayout?

Comment: @MohammedAtif sry, updated the code

Comment: try `ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM` instead of `ALIGN_BOTTOM`, the same for `ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT`. also, what do you mean by `the Icon also is not shown`?

Comment: @marmor the Drawable for FAB is not showing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments try:

```
fablp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
fablp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
```

Regarding the FAB's icon, you probably need the foreground image, not the background, try this:

```
fab.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);
```